# Grid not adapting to window resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I have the following code, which is a simplification of my navbar. It works fine, until I resize my window to the left (make it smaller). The `width: 100%` does not adapt to the new window width and the right-most element overflow outside the window (`100vw` didn't work either).

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto) 1fr repeat(2, auto);
  grid-tepmlate-rows: 1fr;
}

.fourth {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second</span>
    <span>Third</span>
    <span class="fourth">Fourth</span>
    <span>Fifth</span>
    <span>Sixth</span>
<div>
```

So I tried it with some jQuery:

```js
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('div').css('width', $(window).width());
  });
  console.log($(window).width());
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto) 1fr repeat(2, auto);
  grid-tepmlate-rows: 1fr;
}

.fourth {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second</span>
    <span>Third</span>
    <span class="fourth">Fourth</span>
    <span>Fifth</span>
    <span>Sixth</span>
<div>
```

But this is just even more broken. Is there a CSS-only solution, and if not, is it solvable with jQuery?

Comment: If I do `float: right`, for example, it works with no problems. It's just that the grid is not resizing

Comment: Try `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto) 1fr repeat(3, auto);` and remove the `margin-left: auto;` from `.fourth` -- https://fiddle.jshell.net/ydnjkz0j/

Comment: It was the `margin-left: auto`, indeed. I instead now do `float: right`.